# Hierarchy between employee for each department

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have to build a hierarchy between all the employees working in an organisation department wise.

For e.g.  An organisation ABC has 2 departments - Sales, Marketing
Each department has multiple employees, some with same name as well. How can I build a hierarchy for each department. Sample data as below

| Department | Employee | Manager | Expected_Hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | John | Kevin | \Kevin |
| Sales | Adam | John | \John\Adam |
| Sales | Tom | Adam | \John\Adam\Tom |
| Sales | Bruce | Tom | \John\Adam\Tom\Bruce |
| Marketing | Tony | Kevin | \Kevin |
| Marketing | Bruce | Tony | \Tony\Bruce |
| Marketing | John | Tony | \Tony\John |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9THNQ.png)

I tried creating a hierarchical query but that did not work as the employees with same names kept on getting added in the other department hierarchies.

```
create table temp_emp (department varchar2(100 char),empname 
varchar2(100 char), manager varchar2(100 char));

insert into temp_emp values ('Sales','John', 'Kevin');
insert into temp_emp values ('Sales','Adam', 'John');
insert into temp_emp values ('Sales','Tom', 'Adam');
insert into temp_emp values ('Sales','Bruce', 'Tom');
insert into temp_emp values ('Marketing','Tony', 'Kevin');
insert into temp_emp values ('Marketing','Bruce', 'Tony');
insert into temp_emp values ('Marketing','John', 'Tony');
```

Comment: Why do you have `\ManagerName` in some rows and `\SubManagerNames\EmployeeName` in other rows? Why do you not include all the managers and the employee name?

Comment: I understand. This was a mistake in creating the expected_hierarchy data above in my post. It has to be consistent throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(manager,'/')||'/'||empname AS hierarchy
FROM   temp_emp t
START WITH (department, manager) NOT IN (SELECT department, empname
                                         FROM   temp_emp)
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR department = department
AND    PRIOR empname    = manager;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| DEPARTMENT | EMPNAME | MANAGER | HIERARCHY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marketing | Tony | Kevin | /Kevin/Tony |
| Marketing | Bruce | Tony | /Kevin/Tony/Bruce |
| Marketing | John | Tony | /Kevin/Tony/John |
| Sales | John | Kevin | /Kevin/John |
| Sales | Adam | John | /Kevin/John/Adam |
| Sales | Tom | Adam | /Kevin/John/Adam/Tom |
| Sales | Bruce | Tom | /Kevin/John/Adam/Tom/Bruce |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I6sfnjPn)